# Spring static self-reference class pattern use cases

Tags: java, spring, static, self-reference

I recently stumbled upon a code like the one below.

```
@Component    
public class Instance {

    private static Instance instance;
    private final Template template;

    public Instance(Template template) {
        this.template = template;
        Instance.instance = this;
    }

    static void someMethod() {
        instance.template.doSomething();
    }
}
```

From my understanding this is done so that you could use template in a static method but then again you could just inject the Instance class to where you need it and avoid static method altogether.

```
@Component    
public class Instance {

    private final Template template;

    public Instance(Template template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    void someMethod() {
        template.doSomething();
    }
}
```

I am curious as to what is the use case of such pattern and if there are any alternatives to that, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[edit]** Just realised that the static field is `private` and therefore not exposable to the outer non-Spring world as I've interpreted below.

In that case I don't see any reason whatsoever to do this. The `Instance` bean is singleton by virtue of the Spring 'singleton' scope. So introducing this static private field doesn't make any sense therefore what you are suggesting is obviously the correct approach.

---

**[before edit]**

I guess this is done to expose `Instance` Spring bean to other code that is not Spring-related i.e. some non-Spring code can invoke `Instance.someMethod()`

But still this is a bad idea in my opinion as it adds the non-intuitive responsibility within the Spring bean: "How can I be accessible from outside Spring?". And what do we do then for another Spring bean? Add this Spring-anti-pattern to all Spring beans?

If this is needed in one or just few places I would suggest using [@Configurable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Configurable.html) to Spring-ify a class where you can inject the dependency as needed.

Otherwise, I would suggest the application to take care of this "Spring to non-Spring" interop centrally and agnostic to beans: Maybe hide upon startup the [ApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) and retrieve beans internally exponsing a Spring-agnostic API.

Comment: `instance` being `private` doesn't prevent you from calling `Instance.someMethod()`, thus I don't see the reason edit. The prior answer is still correct.

Comment: @Tom thanks for that. I primarily meant to be accessed from some other non-Spring code as Instance.someMethod()

Comment: And that is still possible (every class can call `Instance.someMethod()` as long as it is placed in the same package) and I also agree that this was surely the main reason why the code was implemented like this. I guess I'm missing something here, because the code looks like one wanted to expose `someMethod` to either a non-Spring class or to something static and used that way and your answer explains that correctly. I still don't see how the `private` modify on `instance` changes something.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up. This is exactly the kind of explanation I was hoping for!